# Generate filter mechanism that matches exactly for double quotes strings and contains like functionality for single qoutes

Tags: java, search, filter, javacc

I have the challenging task of creating a "google-like" functionality for our application. It is required to develop it by using [javacc](https://javacc.java.net). The requirements are to work the following way:

- if I have a query string "text text" i should match one-to-one, so in a list ["text text text", "text text", "text text text text"] it should match just "text text"
- if I have a query string 'text text' i should match using contains, so in a list ["text", "text text text", "text text", "text text text text"] it should match ["text text text", "text text", "text text text text"]

As it's first time I am dealing with javacc, I would highly appreciate some input.

Thank you

Comment: So what is your question?  If you just need a regular expression for a string see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156948/javacc-quote-with-escape-character , or check out any of the many grammars in the JavaCC repository for languages that have strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some input.  The regular expressions you need are

```
  "\""              // Double quote
  ( ~["\""] )*      // Zero or more characters that aren't double quotes
  "\""              // Double quote
```

and

```
  "'"               // Single quote
  ( ~["'"] )*       // Zero or more characters that aren't single quotes
  "'"               // Single quote
```

Of course you can get fancier.  In programming languages, usually newlines and such are not allowed within quotes and there are special ways to quote quotes and other characters.  But this is a start.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion after a couple of trials. Thank you!